# NodeJs async SyntaxError

Tags: node.js

I don't understand why is not working.
The compiler is asking for the async in the await function in router, and I have the async in router exports.

[The problem in IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUSZf.png)

Server:

```
const http = require("http");
const router = require("./router");

module.exports = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log(request.url);
  
    try {
        const content = await router(request, response);
        return response.end(content);
    } catch (error) {
        
        response.writeHead(404,{
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        });
        response.end(`<h1>${error.message}</h1>`);
    }
});
```

Router:

```
const { parse } = require("url");
const indexAction = require("./actions/index");

const routes = {
  "/": indexAction,
};

module.exports = async (request, response) => {
  const parseUrl = parse(request.url, true);
  const route = parseUrl.pathname;

  if (routes[route]) {
    return await routes[route](request, response, parseUrl.query);
  }

  throw new Error("404 Not Found");
};
```

Comment: Please post your code in text form and not image form, as this makes it easier for others to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: please post the code and error, not the image

Comment: Do you mean like this?

Comment: you need to make the callback async `module.exports = http.createServer(async (request, response) => {`

Comment: either what @MWO suggests or use promise chaining.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just to be clear. So when I use await inside a lambda function, I need also to use it in the parameters of the lambda function?

Comment: Change this line `module.exports = http.createServer((request, response) => {` to this `module.exports = http.createServer(async (request, response) => {`